# In windows service start/custom/UUID/data0/ what is the data0 for my event like install?

Tags: c#, windows, events, service

I am developing a c# trigger start window service

what should I pass data in this command for my event like install event etc. command:    start/custom/UUID/data0/

what is data0?

https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/ServiceTriggerEditor/sc.html